# Forward reference confusion

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

With reference to the following code, I do not understand why the `move constructor` is called both with an `lvalue` and `rvalue`. I would expect `copy ctor` to be printed when i pass an `lvalue` to the `push` method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class my_obj
{
public:
    my_obj()
    {
        cout << "default ctor\n";
    }

    my_obj(const my_obj& other)
    {
        cout << "copy ctor\n";
    }

    my_obj(my_obj&&  other)
    {
        cout << "move ctor\n";
    }      
};

class test
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void push(T&& object)
    {
         print(forward<T>(object));
    }

    template<typename T>
    void print(T&& a)
    {
        cout << "move\n";
        my_obj temp = forward<T>(a);
    }

    template<typename T>
    void print(T& a)
    {
        cout << "val\n";
        my_obj temp = forward<T>(a);
    }
};


int main()
{
    my_obj obj;
    test f;

    f.push(obj); // why is move ctor called here? shouldnt it be copy ctor since not rvalue
    cout << "\nPUSHING TEMP\n\n";
    f.push(my_obj {});
}
```

output:

```
default ctor
val
move ctor

PUSHING TEMP

default ctor
move
move ctor
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In here:

```
template<typename T>
void print(T& a)
{
    cout << "val\n";
    my_obj temp = forward<T>(a);
}
```

`a` isn't a forwarding reference, it's an lvalue reference. The type `T` isn't a reference type. So `forward<T>(a)` behaves the same as `move(a)`. The special case for forwarding references is that the template parameter deduces to a reference type, and forwarding with a reference type yields an lvalue.

You just want `my_obj temp = a;`

Comment: @pyjg No reason to feel stupid. Everybody had to learn this at some point.

Comment: so the right fix would be `my_obj temp = a;` in that function?

Comment: @pyjg Yep. The point of forwarding is to preserve the value category, but here we know we have an lvalue. Typically, you only want to `forward` forwarding references - and you don't have one, so don't `forward`. (The "correct" forwarding would be `forward<T&>(a)` but please don't actually write that).

Comment: got it, thank you for the explanation it makes a lot of sense now :)

Answer (score 2):

The move constructor is called because you are using `std::forward` without a forwarding reference (don't do that please). Basically, this line is the culprit:

```
my_obj temp = forward<T>(a);
```

Here, `T` is a `my_obj`. Remember that `std::forward` is just a glorified cast. In your case, it is equivalent to:

```
my_obj temp = static_cast<my_obj&&>(a);
```

So you are casting `a` to a rvalue reference, and an rvalue has move semantics, so you see the move constructor being called. You are basically getting the behavior of `std::move`.